# What is the difference between The Jsoup.parse() and Jsoup.ParseBodyFragment() in java?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

class JsoupTester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String html = "<html><head><title>Sample Title</title></head><body><p>Sample Content</p></body></html>";
                Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
                System.out.println(document.body());
                Document document2 = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
                System.out.println(document2.body());


        }
}
```

What is the difference between The Jsoup.parse() and Jsoup.ParseBodyFragment() in java as both give the same output?

output :

```
shiv@OS:~/CodeSnippets/TrashCode$ javac JsoupTester.java 
shiv@OS:~/CodeSnippets/TrashCode$ java JsoupTester
<body>
 <p>Sample Content</p>
</body>
<body>
 <title>Sample Title</title>
 <p>Sample Content</p>
</body>
```

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`parseBodyFragment​`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html), which says: *Parse a fragment of HTML, with the assumption that **it forms the body of the HTML**.* --- As such, the correct call would be `parseBodyFragment("<p>Sample Content</p>")` vs `parse("<html> ... full HTML here ... </html>")`. --- "**Fragment**" means *"only the content of `<body>`"*.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the [documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html), the parse  method takes a full HTML document as input and the parseBodyFragment method takes an HTML body fragment as input.

You can test differences by running [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/jshell/index.html):

```
jshell --class-path jsoup-1.13.1.jar
```

If you use an HTML document with a `<title>` in the `<head>`:

```
var html = "<html><head><title>aaa</title><body>bbb</body></html>"
```

Calling `Jsoup.parse(html)` gives:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>aaa</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     bbb
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

and calling `Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html)` gives:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head></head>
>   <body>
>     <title>aaa</title>bbb
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

So the main difference is that `Jsoup.parseBodyFragment` will always give you an empty head and `Jsoup.parse` is able to parse the head section.

Answer (score 0):

The website can be built using (as well) HTML fragments i.e. snippets of HTLM, that don't contain `<html><body>` tags.

E.g.

```
<p id="1p">LOrem ipsum...</p>
<p id="2p">Ipsum LOrem ipsum...</p>
```

This is what `parseBodyFragment()` for: parsing HTML snippets which are not the complete HTML files.

When this method called Jsoup adds `<html><body>` to the beginning and `</html></body>` to the end of HTML fragment.

This method should not be used for full HTML documents, use `parse()` instead.